# Jquery button action for each listitem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a joblisting and want to program an action for each jobitem,
but my code apparently makes the mods to the last item in the list and i don't get why.

can someone help me?

this is the HTML

```
<div class="joblist">
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the Js (Jquery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.joblist-item').each(function(){
        thisjob = this;
        $('.readmore',thisjob).click( function(){
            $('.joblist-item-content',thisjob).css("background", "red");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just `$('.readmore').click(function(){$(this).parent().prev().css("background", "red");});`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare a variable with `let` or `const` (or `var`).

Also  putting `thisjob` together with `this`, doesn't make sense to me. Why would you want to put a click event on both a parent and a child?

Here is how I made it working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.joblist-item').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      let content = $(this).find('.joblist-item-content')
      $(content).css("background", "red");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="joblist">
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `thisjob` globally, so on every iteration the reference is kept to the same element (the last one in the iteration), you just need to prefix it with the keyword `var`, `let` or `const`: `var thisjob = this`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.joblist-item').each(function(){
        var thisjob = this;
        $('.readmore', thisjob).on('click', function(){
            $('.joblist-item-content', thisjob).css("background", "red");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="joblist">
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="joblist-item">
  <div class="joblist-item-content"> ... </div>
  <div class="joblist-item-cta"><div class="readmore">read more</div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```